# Issues opening a .czi file (zeiss microscope file) tile with aicspylibczi

Tags: coordinates, dimensions

I am trying to open a tiled (mosaic) .czi file with aicspylibczi but I receive the following error message:
"The coordinates are overspecified = you have specified a Dimension or Dimension value that is not valid. Scene index -1 ∉ [0, 0)".

My code is just:

```
import aicspylibczi
img_tile = path+"JM200718_1_Out.czi"
execute_czi = aicspylibczi.CziFile(img_tile)
```

, I have not specified any coordinate, and because I can open with no problem .czi files that have 300 z and 2 channels, but only one xy start coodinate (not mosaic files), I feel the probleme lies in the fact that my images are mosaic files.
Does any one has an idea to how to get around that? It is the very first step of my code so I feel stuck in my attempts to see what is the issue here.
All the examples I found, including the specific one for mosaic fils is te one I wrote (witch do not work).
ex: https://pypi.org/project/aicspylibczi/

Thanks for taking the time to read me!